# javascript send local file to api

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

I'm developing an electron app which must call an api to replace (update) file X in server by file Y which is in my computer.
The user download file X from Server in order to edit it, (this file will be named file Y in my computer).
When the user finish to edit file Y, i check if both files X and Y are differents and i call the api in order to replace file X by file Y. I don't need to put file Y in a form before calling api, i want to do it without form.
Only my request payload is different from what i expect to have, there is no problem in my request headers

I expect to have something like that [image: what i expect]
and i get this
[image: what i get]

Here is what i do

```
 const fs = require('fs');
  let fileY = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('gitignore.txt'));
  let form = new FormData();
  form.append("type", "jur_document");
  form.append("file", fileY, 'gitignore.txt');
  form.append("saveActionType", "SAVEMAJOR");
  form.append("attributes", "MIMETYPE=text/plain");

  let settings = {
    "async": true,
    "url": `${Constante.URL}/documents`,
    "method": "POST",
    "type": "POST",
    "headers": {
      // "Content-Type": "text/plain",
      "Authorization": sessionStorage.getItem('authorization')
    },
    "processData": false,
    "contentType": false,
    "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
    "data": form
  };

  $.ajax(settings)
    .done((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }).fail(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: You must set an HTTP header for `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I do it but I get the same result

Comment: Please re-read the `jQuery.ajax()` documentation. You have conflicting settings in your settings object that will cause all sorts of issues. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Here is my new setting but it still doesn't take the file

<pre>
let settings = {
        "url": `${Constante.URL}/documents`,
        "method": "POST",
        "type": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          "Authorization": sessionStorage.getItem('authorization')
        },
        "processData": false,
        "contentType": false,
        "mimeType": "text/plain",
        "data": form
      };
</pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally get the solution
I read my file and create a blob which i use to recreate my file

```
  const fs = require('fs');
  let buffer = fs.readFileSync(`${app.getAppPath()}/test.txt`);
  let fileY = new File([new Uint8Array(buffer)], 'test.txt', {
    type: 'text/plain'
  });

  form.append("file", fileY);
```

and here is ajax settings

```
  let settings = {
    "url": `${Constante.URL}/documents`,
    "type": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": sessionStorage.getItem('authorization')
    },
    "processData": false,
    "contentType": false,
    "data": form
  };
```